# quartz.config or quartz.properties

Tags: c#, config, quartz.net

Is  there a difference between the names `quartz.config` and `quartz.properties`; i.e. does Quartz.NET distinguish between them, or does it look for both?

I have a project which is currently configured by a `quartz.config` file, but I would like to use the `properties` (or any other) extension instead. Can I just change the names and expect things to work, or will I need to point Quartz in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference.

They're basically Name-Value-Pairs.

You can put half in .xml, and code up half of them if you want.

I tend to put most/all in .xml.